# 'str' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

```
connection_1 = MySQLdb.connect(host ="localhost:3306",user = " ",password = " ",db ="hospital")

def oracle1_database():
    connection_1 = Connection_entry.get()
    user = Username_entry.get()
    passw = Password_entry.get()
    db = connection_1
    print(db)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    print("xz1",cursor)
    a1 = cursor.execute("select * from a1")
    print(a1)

    try:
        cursor.execute(a1)
        myresult = cursor.fetchall()

        for x in myresult:
            savequery_data = x
            print(savequery_data)

        print("Query executed successfully")
    except:
        db.rollback()
        print("Error occured")
```

Please tell me how to solve the error.

I create a GUI in that I take 3 input 1 is connection string, 2 names, 3 is a password with the help of GUI when I enter the connection

```
string(MySQLdb.connect(host ="localhost:3306", user = " ", password = " ", DB =" hospital"))
```

it gives detail of the database query which I have written in the program I have multiple databases (Oracle, MongoDB, SQL....) when I write connection string in 1st input box it takes the database which I want and runs the query. There I write code but I get an error

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\python\envs\hospital data\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1883, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
>
> File "D:/hospital data/mis1.py", line 32, in oracle1_database
> cursor = a21.cursor()
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cursor'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z49kH.png)

Comment: What is "the error"? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\envs\hospital data\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/hospital data/mis1.py", line 32, in oracle1_database
    cursor = a21.cursor()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Comment: I am facing the error

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't use the comment section. Additionally, share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: okay sir I update there

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you exactly what's wrong. You're trying to call `.cursor()` on a string, and strings don't have a cursor.

This sets `connection_1` to a string:

```
connection_1 = Connection_entry.get()
```

This sets `db` to `connection_1` which is still a string:

```
db = connection_1
```

This tries to call `.cursor()` on `db`, which is still a string:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
```

The problem seems to be the first of those lines. You initialize `connection_1` properly but then you reset it to a string. Don't do that.